# Prepopulating initiation form with approvers of the workflow from a list

Tags: workflow, infopath

I am using a 2010 workflow template to create a workflow in SP Designer 2013. I am trying to Prepopulate workflow a initiation form with approvers from a SharePoint list based on the person who starts the workflow.

I created data connections to the list and created rules on Form Load and I was able to see the Approvers when I preview the initiation InfoPath form but when the workflow is started the initiation form is not prepopulating.